# UTF-8 but still not showing ÆØÅ (danish chars)

Tags: ajax, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Take a look at this:
http://thebekker.dk/_skole/GFeksamen/

You can see the 2nd menu item show some weird sign, instead of "Ø"

Ive set utf-8 in meta, and even tryed with AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in .htaccess...

Still no result, if i change to ISO-8859-1 which works fine, but that makes problem when i start making ajax calls for content...

I dont get it?
How do i get it to use UTF-8 and show ÆØÅ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you *declare* that your content is encoded in UTF-8 with the meta tags or default charset, then **your content needs to be actually encoded in UTF-8.** The fact that it shows correctly when declaring your content to be encoded in ISO-8859 means that your content is *actually* encoded in ISO-8859. Save your source code file as UTF-8 or otherwise make sure that your content is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: How do i then re-encode easiest? 
Ive tried to open the file in notepad, and saving with UTF-8, and uploading again with filezilla.
Still no luck..

Comment: Depends on your editor. I wouldn't call Notepad an editor. Get something like Notepad++ at least and make sure the file is not reencoded during upload. I have no real idea about the pitfalls on Windows here since I don't use it, maybe you can open a new question specifically about the software you're using...

Comment: I found out!
I oversaw that it acually saved the weird sign now, so i can just change them to the right chars now.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the source file in "Western European (Windows)" in EditPlus text editor did it for me + in PHP I used utf8_encode.

Answer (score -2):

you can set this characters with unicode like € or so many others. In my company we work with many translations and languages like france, that has many special chars.

set your website encoding type to utf-8 and use encodings like utf8_encode in php

or manually: http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/online-tools/